# Merge Query With Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello im using SQL Server i want merge data by categori 
i  have a query like this

```
SELECT a.NamaMerk, b.NamaTipe from MsMerk as a inner join MsTipe  as b 
on a.ID_Merk = b.ID_Merk where a.FlagActive='Y' and b.FlagActive='Y' and a.ID_Merk = b.ID_Merk and b.ID_Tipe = b.ID_Tipe
```

This Show data

[image]

i want data Show like this

> Samsung :   Galaxy S7

```
         Galaxy S8
```

> Asus   :    Zenfone 4

```
         Zenfone 5
```

Like a merge data by category, help me thank's

Comment: So as an example, you want the second row Samsung value to be empty string? Why do you want to do this though? Knowing might help with a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. I use row_number to rank by NamaMerk and then when it's greater than 1 I set it to empty string

```
    SELECT CASE 
         WHEN T.rank > 1 THEN '' 
         ELSE T.NamaMerk 
       END        AS 'NamaMerk', 
       T.NamaTipe AS 'NamaTipe' 
FROM   (SELECT a.NamaMerk, 
               b.NamaTipe, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY a.NamaMerk 
                   ORDER BY b.NamaTipe) AS 'RANK' 
        FROM   msmerk AS a 
               INNER JOIN mstipe AS b 
                       ON a.id_merk = b.id_merk 
        WHERE  a.flagactive = 'Y' 
               AND b.flagactive = 'Y' 
               AND a.id_merk = b.id_merk ) T
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (NamaMerk VARCHAR(10), NamaTipe VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tab
VALUES ('Samsung','Galaxy S7'),('Samsung','Galaxy S6'),
('Apple','iPhone 5'),('LG','G5'),('Asus','Zenfone 4'),
('Asus','Zenfone 7'),('Xiami', 'Mi Note 3'),
('Asus','Zenfone 5')

;WITH cte AS 
(
 SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NamaMerk ORDER BY NamaTipe) AS Rn
 FROM @tab
)
SELECT CASE WHEN Rn=1 THEN NamaMerk + ':' + NamaTipe 
  ELSE REPLICATE(' ',LEN(NamaTipe)) + NamaTipe END AS Result
FROM cte;
```

Using Row_Number, when it's 1, concatenate NamaMerk and NamTipe else space plus NamaTipe.

I think these you might have to do it in the SSRS, since it has to do with the display.

Comment: The filling with blank spaces only works properly if you use mono-spaced font. A good solution nonetheless.